# apache memory gradually increasing over time with python/django/tastypie

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, tastypie

I'm getting gradual increase of memory over time in Apache running django/tastypie. Traffic does increase, but I expect to see a gradual decrease of memory over time.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers           6
MinSpareThreads       12
MaxSpareThreads       24
ThreadLimit           48
ThreadsPerChild       24
MaxClients            24
MaxRequestsPerChild    0
MaxMemFree          1024
</IfModule>
```

daemon process:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.com processes=24 threads=24
```

Reports from New Relic

[image]

[image]

Is my thinking flawed? If memory eventually stables and goes linear, I really don't care if memory frees over time as long as it never goes past a certain threshold. I have two load balanced machines and they are both same setup and doing the same thing.

Everything is running great otherwise and super fast.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

One day of runtime with a low number of requests makes it hard to tell if you're leaking memory.  To me your graphs look reasonable, but there are many variables so it's hard to tell for certain.

If you're concerned about leaks you can try using the [`maximum-requests`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) WSGIDaemonProcess option to restart processes after they serve that many requests.

Also, do you really need 24 WSGI processes?  Each one will have its own python interpreter, and so over time will consume 24 * (1 python/django/tastypie stack).  I'd suggest load testing and reducing the number of processes accordingly.  Also check out [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/modwsgi/Hakr6FjRVQM) from Graham Dumpleton.

Comment: Thank you, the graphs in that post help out in determining how the processes to threads works..

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache MPM and mod_wsgi daemon configuration together are quite broken. I cant provide a detailed answer right now as I am on holidays and travelling away from home, but go watch my PyCon talk and I will try and followup later once I see you have watched that and tried fixing your configuration yourself and posted a followup here.

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

---

UPDATE 1

BTW, if you look at the capacity analysis report under New Relic for your actual web application as monitored by the New Relic Python agent, you should see how under utilised your capacity is due to the over the top number of processes/threads you are using for daemon mode of mod_wsgi. For details about the capacity analysis report see:

- http://blog.newrelic.com/2012/09/11/introducing-capacity-analysis-for-python/

Comment: I believe I'm a bit confused when the specific site's apache config is thrown into the mix (ex. WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.com processes=24 threads=24). I've lowered apache values to:     StartServers           2
    MinSpareThreads       25
    MaxSpareThreads       50
    ThreadLimit           50
    ThreadsPerChild       25
    MaxClients            75
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
    MaxMemFree          1024, and I've lowered the wsgi file to WSGIDaemonProcess api.chanj.com threads=25. Please note that I'm not serving up ANY static files, and this is the only site on the box.

Comment: What are the downsides of running a single process through the wsgi daemon?

Comment: To clarify, the Apache worker processes proxy to the mod_wsgi daemon processes, so there is no point processes*threads of the daemon process group being more than MaxClients of Apache as the Apache worker processes will never be able to proxy more than MaxClients requests at the same time. Anything for the daemon process group above MaxClients is therefore just wasted and through gradual activation of the processes/threads over time, will see a gradual memory increase until it levels off at its steady state level.

Comment: Running a single daemon process is often fine for most sites as they never have enough traffic anyway, so really doesn't matter what you put. In practice though, a better configuration may be 5 threads per process and as many processes are then needed to meet capacity requirements such that capacity utilisation is down around 30-50% for typical high throughput time. The extra capacity would be there just in case of spikes in traffic. Anyway, it all depends on your application and the New Relic capacity analysis report is one way of trying to tune it.